# Solr 7.1.0 Spellcheck each word?

Tags: solr, spell-checking

/select?q=Spannish

Returns spellcheck as expected.

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":5,
    "params":{
      "q":"Spannish",
      "fq":"auctionId:71",
      "_":"1511301093854"}},
  "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]
  },
  "spellcheck":{
    "suggestions":[
      "spannish",{
        "numFound":5,
        "startOffset":0,
        "endOffset":8,
        "origFreq":0,
        "suggestion":[{
            "word":"spanish",
            "freq":343},
          {
[...]
    "correctlySpelled":false,
    "collations":[
      "collation",{
        "collationQuery":"spanish",
        "hits":5,
        "misspellingsAndCorrections":[
          "spannish","spanish"]},
[...]
```

However,

/select?q=Spannish Rifle

Returns results for just "Rifle" and believes the query is correctly spelled.

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "q":"Spannish Rifle",
      "fq":"auctionId:71",
      "_":"1511301093854"}},
    "response":{"numFound":839,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
[...]
```

My spellcheck request handler has the following defaults

```
  <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
  <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
  <str name="spellcheck">on</str>
  <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">true</str>
  <str name="spellcheck.count">10</str>
  <str name="spellcheck.alternativeTermCount">5</str>
  <str name="spellcheck.maxResultsForSuggest">5</str>
  <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
  <str name="spellcheck.collateExtendedResults">true</str>
  <str name="spellcheck.maxCollationTries">10</str>
  <str name="spellcheck.maxCollations">5</str>
```

And this is the search component

```
<searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
  <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">text_ws</str>
  <lst name="spellchecker">
    <str name="classname">solr.IndexBasedSpellChecker</str>
    <str name="spellcheckIndexDir">./spellchecker</str>
    <str name="field">_spelling_</str>
    <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
    <str name="distanceMeasure">org.apache.lucene.search.spell.LevensteinDistance</str>
    <str name="accuracy">0.65</str>
  </lst>
</searchComponent>
```

_spelling_ uses the field type text_ws

```
<fieldType name="text_ws" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
<field name="_spelling_" type="text_ws" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
```

How can I get solr to tell me that "Spannish" is spelled incorrectly

Thanks.

Comment: please show fieldType for _spelling_ field

Comment: uses text_ws, added with more info. @Mysterion